# Trying to figure out how tax lines work when creating Shopify order via API

Tags: rest, shopify

I am posting the following to the Shopify API create order endpoint and receiving a response without tax lines that are filled. I haven't seen anything on the internet on this, other than that Shopify doesn't offer another endpoint for just taxes. So, I am trying to figure out if tax lines are supposed to be generated automatically in the order response when creating an order via the API or if I have to include the tax lines in the request in order for tax lines to be included, because I know when I create an order in the admin the tax lines are automatically calculated and included for me?:

```
   {
  "order": {
    "email": "some@email.com",
    "financial_status": "paid",
    "fulfillment_status": null,
    "send_receipt": true,
    "send_fulfillment_receipt": true,
    "note": "Created by somename",
    "line_items": [
      {
        "variant_id": 21718275463,
        "quantity": 1,
        "price": 99,
        "requires_shipping": true,
        "product_id": 6820646151
      },
      {
        "variant_id": 21717700871,
        "quantity": 1,
        "price": 1000,
        "requires_shipping": true,
        "product_id": 6820646151
      },
      {
        "variant_id": 21717690055,
        "quantity": 1,
        "price": 555,
        "requires_shipping": true,
        "product_id": 6821668807
      }
    ],
    "processing_method": "offsite",
    "shipping_address": {
      "first_name": "Chris",
      "address1": "10101 Musick Road",
      "phone": "9999999999",
      "city": "St. Louis",
      "zip": "63123",
      "province": "MO",
      "country": "United States",
      "last_name": "Becker",
      "name": "Chris Becker",
      "country_code": "US",
      "province_code": "MO"
    },
    "source_name": "somename",
    "taxes_included": false,
    "shipping_lines": [
      {
        "title": "standard",
        "price": 0.00,
        "code": null,
        "source": "brand owner on shopify",
        "carrier_identifier": null,
        "tax_lines": null
      }
    ],
    "tags": "some Order"
  }
}
```

Comment: https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/order#create

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tax lines won't automatically generate in Shopify API order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37620714/tax-lines-wont-automatically-generate-in-shopify-api-order)

Comment: Did you figure this out? I think I am dealing with a similar issue, but with both shipping and tax.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a useful documentation about tax: https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/location

Tax are not automatically calculated from cart.js ajax api. They just give a clue whether tax is already included in the price or not. If not, then it can be added with the bill.